# CollectionView method cellForItemAt indexPath: not being called (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have used `UICollectionViewController` and I'm trying to add images to my collection view cell but `UICollectionView` method is not being called.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CircularCollectionViewCell
        cell.imageName = images[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: What's the number of rows? When do you have populated the `images` array? Did you `yourCollectionView.reloadData()` if needed? In main thread? Is it really a UICollectionViewController or a UIViewController where you added a UICollectionView? If that's an added UICollectionView, what its frame?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya I've used collectionVC. Do I need to conform to delegate and datasource?

Comment: Do you use Assets (xcassets) or a manual folder: How did you add your images into your project?

Comment: @Larme my `images` array is populating but `cellForItemAt` method is still not called. I've used a manual folder and made it a reference folder with blue icon.

Comment: If you use UICollectionViewController, the datasource is already set. I thought that `images` was empty, that's not the case? Call `reloadData()` once done?

Comment: Where should i call `reloaddata()`? i've called in `viewdidload()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Show your `viewdidload()` code

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
     self.collectionView.reloadData()

}` @iOSDev

Comment: Where you are adding your images to `images` array?

Comment: In collectionVC class before `viewdidload()` 

`let images: [String] = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "png", inDirectory: "Images")`

Comment: @FarazA.Khan Check my answer

Comment: @FarazA.Khan  you are registering wrong cell i think `override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() collectionView.register(CircularCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) self.collectionView.reloadData() }`

Comment: @KishanBhatiya Doesn’t work either.

Comment: @KishanBhatiya In that case `cellForItemAt` method will be called and crashed. But here `cellForItemAt` is not at all called

Comment: @KishanBhatiya app is running without any crash.

Comment: @FarazA.Khan can you show code for `sizeForItemAt` because if item size is too big  for collectionViewFlowLayout's height then also `cellforRowAt` not being called

Comment: @KishanBhatiya I’ve not used method sizeForItemAt

Comment: Is `images` empty or not? Because if that's the case, that's clearly there that is the issue.

Comment: @Larme images is not empty because I’m checking it in numberOfItemsInSection() method by printing it’s count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: *CellforRow at:indexPath* method won't be called if the size or position of the collectionView is changed before reload, make sure you're not doing that.

Comment: How do i check this?

Comment: you changing any other constraints may indirectly affect the size or position of collectionview so just try calling collectionView.layoutIfneeded() method and force to reload the collectionView in main thread.

Comment: you mean i should call `layoutifneeded()` in `viewdidload` ?

Comment: In a `UICollectionViewController` that shouldn't be the case. I don't think it's modally presented in a strange size.

Answer (score 5):

The `cellForItemAtIndexPath` will not get called if you do not provide the **content size information** to the collection view.

What you can do is set up the `collectionViewLayout` as shown below:

```
 let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
 flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
 collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Answer (score 2):

If your **UICollectionView** have not proper content size, then cellForItemAt will not called.

I have two solution for it.

1. Call collectionView.layoutIfneeded() before reloading collectionView.
2. Add collectionViewLayout in main thread before reloading collectionView which helps to adjust content size.

> ```
>  DispatchQueue.main.async {
>       let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
>       flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
>       self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
>  }
>  self.collectionView.reloadData()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In `UICollectionViewController` subclasses `delegate` and `dataSource` are set by default.

And 0 is used in datasource methods by default. You need to change these values.

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {        
    return 1
}    

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
    print(images.count)
    return images.count
}
```

Comment: I have done this. This prints the count of images. Which is 14.

Comment: @FarazA.Khan Still `cellForItemAt` isn't called? Do you have breakpoints in `cellForItemAt` method?

Comment: Obviously I’ve put the breakpoints. Still it’s not being called.

Answer (score 0):

One possible situation is that the size of the collection view is zero. When the size is zero (either width or height = 0), `cellForItemAt` won't get called.

In my case, I put my `UICollectionView` inside a `UIStackView` with `Alignment` set to `Leading`, and forgot to set the width of to be equal to the stack view.

Answer (score -2):

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```